# OpenCV - Correctly recovering the pose and landmark positions from 2d image points

Tags: python, opencv, 3d-reconstruction, pose-estimation, structure-from-motion

I'm trying to do 3D scene reconstruction and camera pose estimation on video input, however the camera positions are not matching what I am seeing in the video.

Here is the code I wrote to recover the pose and landmark positions

```
    def SfM(self, points1, points2):
        x = 800 / 2
        y = 600 / 2

        fov = 80 * (math.pi / 180)
        f_x = x / math.tan(fov / 2)
        f_y = y / math.tan(fov / 2)

        # intrinsic camera matrix
        K = np.array([[f_x, 0, x],
                      [0, f_y, y],
                      [0, 0, 1]])

        #find fundamental matrix
        E, mask = cv2.findFundamentalMat(np.float32(points2), np.float32(points1), cv2.FM_8POINT)
        #get rotation matrix and translation vector
        points, R, t, mask = cv2.recoverPose(E, np.float32(points2), np.float32(points1), K, 500)
        
        #caculate the new camera position based on the translation, camPose is the previous camera position
        self.cam_xyz.append([self.camPose[0] + t[0], self.camPose[1] + t[1], self.camPose[2] + t[2]])

        #calculate the extrinsic matrix
        C = np.hstack((R, t))

        #calculate the landmark positions
        for i in range(len(points2)):
            #convert coordinates into a 3x1 array
            pts2d = np.asmatrix([points2[i][0], points2[i][1], 1]).T
            #calculate camera matrix
            P = np.asmatrix(K) * np.asmatrix(C)
            #find 3d coordinate
            pts3d = np.asmatrix(P).I * pts2d
            #add to list of landmarks
            self.lm_xyz.append([pts3d[0][0] * self.scale + self.camPose[0],
                                pts3d[1][0] * self.scale + self.camPose[1],
                                pts3d[2][0] * self.scale + self.camPose[2]])

        #update the previous camera position
        self.camPose = [self.camPose[0] + t[0], self.camPose[1] + t[1], self.camPose[2] + t[2]]
```

When I passed in [this video](https://www.pexels.com/video/the-street-in-montreal-business-district-during-community-quarantine-4370833/) I got this as my output
[image: results from running my program]

I can't figure out why it is veering to right when the camera only heads straight in the video. I suspect that I am implementing the `cv2.recoverPose` method incorrectly but I don't no what else I can do to make it better. I put the full code in a [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/tGgzvnDv) in case anyone wants to replicate the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you calculate the essential matrix E with cv.findEssentialMatrix instead? In this way, you calculated the fundamental matrix F, but to recover the pose, you must pass E = K^T * F * K, w/ K = camera matrix